# how to set file descriptor non-blocking?

Tags: c, linux, nonblocking, epoll

I have two ways to set file descriptor non-blocking.

```
fcntl(conn_fd, F_SETFD, (fcntl(conn_fd, F_GETFD, 0)|O_NONBLOCK));
```

or

```
 fcntl(conn_fd, F_SETFD, (fcntl(conn_fd, F_GETFD)|O_NONBLOCK));
```

and

```
void setnonblocking(int sock) {
    int opt;

    opt = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL);
    if (opt < 0) {
        printf("fcntl(F_GETFL) fail.");
    }
    opt |= O_NONBLOCK;
    if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, opt) < 0) {
        printf("fcntl(F_SETFL) fail.");
    }
}
```

why the function setnonblocking can set file descriptor non-blocking .but the other can't.I use this when epoll get a new connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`O_NONBLOCK` is a file status flag, not a file descriptor flag.

Maybe, in your `fcntl(conn_fd, F_SETFD, (fcntl(conn_fd, F_GETFD)|O_NONBLOCK));`, you need to change `F_GETFD` to `F_GETFL` and `F_SETFD` to `F_SETFL`, as you need to modify the file status flags, not the file descriptor flags.

Comment: I change F_SETFD to F_SETFL,it works, I need the status of the existing flags.thx!